# AWS Lambda Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How is Lambda pricing calculated?
It is f(Memory*Time, # of Calls, Free Quotas).
So I setup my Lambda with memory of 1GB and a max time of 60 seconds.
Assume I have 10,000 calls and the average call time is 30 seconds.
How would I calculate the Memory*Time, do I use the max time of 60 seconds or the average call time of 30 seconds?
if it is 30 seconds then the max time set up with the Lambda is to put a cap on max processing time and is used for a run-away process.
Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 1):

You use the average call time. The max is indeed to prevent run-away processes and limit the costs of each call.

Comment: Thanks, I am surprised that don't point that out when setting the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You are billed by the number of requests and the duration of those requests.  In addition you're charged for any other services you use.  E.g. S3 storage.

> Lambda counts a request each time it starts executing in response to an event notification or invoke call, including test invokes from the console. You are charged for the total number of requests across all your functions
>
> Duration is calculated from the time your code begins executing until it returns or otherwise terminates, rounded up to the nearest 100ms. The price depends on the amount of memory you allocate to  your function.

For your use case it looks like you fall under the `Free Tier`, the calculations would be:

**Monthly Compute**

```
The monthly compute price is $0.00001667 per GB-s and the free tier provides 400,000 GB-s.

Total compute (seconds) = 10,000 * (30s) = 300,000 seconds

Total compute (GB-s) = 300,000 * 1GB = 300,000 GB-s

Total compute – Free tier compute = Monthly billable compute GB- s

300,000 GB-s – 400,000 free tier GB-s = -100,000 GB-s

Monthly compute charges = Free
```

**Monthly Request Charges**

```
The monthly request price is $0.20 per 1 million requests and the free tier provides 1M requests per month.
Total requests – Free tier requests = Monthly billable requests

10,000 requests – 1M free tier requests = -990,000 Monthly billable requests

Monthly request charges = 0 * $0.2/M = Free
```

If you were to double your requests the `monthly compute charge` would change to $3.33 and your `request charges` would still be free.

**References:**

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

Comment: Thanks,  so Memory if a fixed cost even if you use only 10% of it and duration is what you actually use rounded up to the next 100ms with 100ms min.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code and run:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/4v7uao

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        LambdaFunctionCostCalci();
    }
    
    private static void LambdaFunctionCostCalci()
    {
        bool notExit = true;
        while (notExit)
        {
            double requestNo = 0, memoryUsing = 0, expectedRuntimeInSec = 0;
            const double everyGBSecondUsedCost = 0.00001667;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter No. of invocations:");
            requestNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Execution duration (in Seconds)");
            expectedRuntimeInSec = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Allocated memory (in MB)");
            memoryUsing = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            double computationCharges = requestNo * (expectedRuntimeInSec / 1000) * (memoryUsing / 1024) * everyGBSecondUsedCost;
            Console.WriteLine("Computation Charges (in $): " + computationCharges);

            double requestCharges = (requestNo / 1000000) * 0.2;
            Console.WriteLine("Request Charges (in $): " + requestCharges);

            double totalCharges = computationCharges + requestCharges;
            Console.WriteLine("Total Charges (in Month): " + totalCharges);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to exit");
            notExit = !(Console.ReadLine() == "1");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```